# dynamic validates_length_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I' trying to do a validates_length_of, but specifying the range/minimum/maximum at run time.

For instance, we have a parent model:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children

  # with attributes min_length, max_length
end
```

And a child model:

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent

  # with an attribute reference
end
```

So what I'd like to do in the Child class is:

```
validate :reference_length

def reference_length
  options = { :within => parent.min_length..parent.max_length }
  self.class.validates_length_of :reference, options
end
```

But it doesn't work, is there a way to do that without doing `errors.add(:reference, message) if...`?

Answer (score 2):

Using a lambda function may work:

```
validates_length_of :reference, :minimum => lambda{parent.min_length},
                                :maximum => lambda{parent.max_length}
```

Comment: well, basically you could specify only min_length (and not max_length) so you should not validate maximum length, and viceversa...

Comment: As far as I can tell, `:minimum` and `:maximum` keys did not support lambdas until Rails 5.2.0, approximately 7 years after this answer was submitted. https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/b8b089ef11300fab4625011b942ee4a1fbbdbbbd