# validates_length_of with a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
```

which has 2 attributes: `content`(string) and `max_content_length`(integer)
both are dynamic and set by the user.
I'm trying to validate the length of the `content` string using the `max_content_length` integer like so:

```
validates_length_of :content, maximum: self.max_content_length
```

or like so:

```
validates_length_of :content, maximum: lambda{ self.max_content_length }
```

but validates_length_of throws either a "no method found" or a "maximum must be a nonnegative Integer or Infinity" exception (respectively).

Is there any other way to "register" the `max_content_length` function as the validator for the length?

Thank you!

(I know this is question is possibly a duplicate for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840184/dynamic-validates-length-of) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171748/validates-length-of-with-variables) but unfortunately the answers there are a little off-topic and confusing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your own validation:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :validate_content_length

  private

  def validate_content_length
    if content.length > max_content_length
      errors.add :content, "too long (must be #{max_content_length} characters or less)"
    end
  end

end
```

Help guides here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations